# Windows 8 : Merge files in a directory with file name appended

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am working in windows 8 and i want to merge all txt files in a directory in a single file in such a way that file name is present along with file content.

For example if i have two files, test1.txt and test2.txt with contents as : 
"1
2
3" 
and 
"4
5
6"
then the merged file should be like :-
test1.txt
1
2
3
text2.txt
4
5
6

Is there a command line code for this ? Thank you for your response.

Comment: In general you should try to show some won initiative and attempts on this site.

Answer (score 0):

merge_a_and_b.bat

```
echo a.txt > out.txt
type a.txt >> out.txt
echo. >> out.txt
echo b.txt >> out.txt
type b.txt >> out.txt
```

You could be fancyer

Answer (score 0):

You can use labels like this :

```
set logfile=out.txt

:onefile
set file=%1
echo %file% >> %logfile%
type %file% >> %logfile%
goto :EOF
```

then use the FOR loop to go through your files, and call them each time

```
call :onefile %that_file%
```